# Adding and using aar file with resources in AOSP build

Tags: android-source, android.mk

I need to build an application with android.mk in aosp build tree. I have a custom .arr lib with some resources like drawables,strings..etc, Which resides in the following folder apps/libs/mylib.aar

Anyone can tell me how to include the aar in the android aosp build and use that aar resources in another applications. I already tried the following  method described here in Stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205856/aar-support-in-android-mk

Android.mk of my application is looked like

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res 
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TestSampleAarLib
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES:= sampleaarlib
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES  += android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES  += android-support-v7-gridlayout
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES  += android-support-v13

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay \
    --extra-packages com.myaar.sample.lib
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := AndroidManifest.xml
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := sampleaarlib:libs/sampleaarlib.aar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

If anyone have idea about using resources from aar in AOSP Please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If so, you may want to add your own answer and approve it yourself. It would be useful to others. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add resources from the aar file, please add the following in your android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR +=$(call intermediates-dir-for,JAVA_LIBRARIES,<aar_file_name>,,common)/aar/res
```

Tested and verified in the Android 8.1 version.

NB: In the latest android versions like 9+ resources automatically merged to the project.

Comment: Please paste your mk file here , I am also facing the same problem. It would help me if the complete mk file is there