# Add androidx.viewpager2 to android.mk file

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-source, android.mk, android-viewpager2

Trying to **add androidx.viewpager2** to **android.mk** as below:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    androidx.viewpager2_viewpager2
```

Not able to build code using MMA command and gives below error.

> ninja: error:
>   'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/androidx.viewpager2_viewpager2_intermediates/package-res.apk',
>   needed by
>   'out/target/product/apps/obj/APPS/app_intermediates/package-res.apk',
>   missing and no known rule to make it
>
> **05:31:24 ninja failed with: exit status 1**
>
> failed to build some targets (05:38 (mm:ss))

How can I add androidx.viewpager2 to Android.mk Makefile.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: I don't downvote where someone makes one or two mistakes. I do sometimes downvote if the same errors are made despite a long history of my editing the old ones. We do not have enough editor resource here to maintain the levels of quality we would like, so it helps greatly if we can encourage posters to assist with curation (if only on their own material).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31205856/3801327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add [viewpager2-1.0.0.aar](https://maven.google.com/androidx/viewpager2/viewpager2/1.0.0/viewpager2-1.0.0.aar) into `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` (or `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES`).

Comment: Can you let me know how can add .aar files to Android.mk file?

Comment: @RahulBaradia updated my answer; just seen your question right now.

Answer (score 1):

Add following blocks to support/sync with .AAR library file in Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
.
.
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := App_Name
.
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
.
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := AAR_file-alias
.
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := AAR_file-alias:lib_path/AAR_file.aar
include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```