# How can I add an .aar Library to use in a System Service on AOSP?

Tags: java, makefile, android-source, aar

I am trying to program my own system service, and it requires a .aar library to be included.

I tried it by adding these lines into the Android.mk file in frameworks/base:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := geth
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := geth_android.aar
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .aar
```

In my .java file for the service I just want to be able to import it using:

```
import geth.*;
```

But when I try to compile it, it throws this error:

```
frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/GethService.java:1: error: package geth does not exist
```

Comment: You should use `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34535361/1028256